# Tkinter -tkinter.TclError

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, ttk

I have the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from urllib import urlretrieve

import webbrowser
import ttk
def get_latest_launcher():
    webbrowser.open("johndoe.com/get_latest")
global percent
percent = 0
def report(count, blockSize, totalSize):

   percent += int(count*blockSize*100/totalSize)


homepage =  "http://Johndoe.com"
root = Tk()
root.title("Future of Wars launcher")
Button(text="get latest version", command=get_latest_launcher).pack()

global mpb
mpb = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", variable = percent,length="100",
mode="determinate")                     
mpb.pack()
root.mainloop()
urlretrieve("https://~url~to~my~file.com",
"Smyprogram.exe",reporthook=report)
```

however, if I run this script, it won't display the progressbar, and it will only display the button. It wont even download the file, and the cursor will just blink. However, if I close the gui window, I get the following code:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\downloader.py", line 28 in <module>
   mpb = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", variable =
   percent,length="100",mode="determinate")
  File "C:\Users/user\Desktop\pyttk-0.3\ttk.py" line 1047, in __init__
   Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::progressbar", kw)
  File "C:\Users/user\Desktop\pyttk-0.3\ttk.py", line 574, in __init__
   Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1930, in __init__
   (widgetName, self._w) + extra +  self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: this isn't a Tk applicationNULL main window
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This code works on Linux. I have pyttk 0.3.2 installed using command `pip install pyttk`. (Python 2.7.5)

Comment: @furas really? I'm using windows, and have ttk installed, what problem am I getting?

Comment: I think Tkinter try to run `ttk::progressbar` but Tcl/Tk can't find it. I see you have pyttk on Desktop - I would try to install it using `pip` command it should install it in Python folder and download any dependencies.

Comment: You can try to run Tcl/Tk script (http://paste.tclers.tk/2675) to test whether you have `ttk::progressbar` in `Tcl/Tk`. You can run it `tclsh my_script.tcl`

Comment: Your code and the error don't match up. The error shows `mph = ttk...` and your code shows `mpb = ttk...`. While I realize that's a tiny difference, it makes me wonder if there are more differences. Also, the code you posted runs (not well, but it runs) and doesn't throw the error you say it does.

Comment: @ Bryain Oakley Sorry. It was a typo. I had to type the error by capturing the screen and type it down word by word. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two problems in  your code, though neither of them cause the error you say you're getting.

First, you use a normal python variable as the value of the `variable` attribute of the progress bar. While this will work, it won't work as you expect. You need to create an instance of a tkinter `StringVar` or `IntVar`. Also, you'll need to call the `set` method of that instance in order for the progressbar to see the change.

Second, you should never have code after the call to `mainloop`. Tkinter is designed to terminate once `mainloop` exits (which typically only happens after you destroy the window). You are going to need to move the call to `urlretrieve` somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

`variable = percent` is wrong. You must use Tkinter Variables which are objects. Such as IntVar.